# Possible pandas bug?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, integer

Just looking at some strange behavior in Python/Pandas.

I know the setup is convoluted, I was doing some... challenges.

```
def lucas_n(n):
    '''Return the fist n lucas numbers modulo 1_000_007'''
    my_list = [1,3]
    while len(my_list) < n:
        my_list.append((my_list[-1]+my_list[-2])%1_000_007)
    return my_list

def f(seq):
    '''Look up https://projecteuler.net/problem=739'''
    
    df = pd.Series(seq)
    
    for i in range(len(seq)-1):
        df = df.iloc[1:].cumsum()
        
    return df.iloc[0]

x = lucas_n(1e4)

f(x)

>>> -8402283173942682253
```

In short, `x` is a sequence of positive integers, and `f` applies consecutive `.iloc[1:].cumsum()` operations.

And the output is negative...

Is this a bug? A data type issue?

Comment: Looks like an integer overflow or smth, because everything works as intended with `1e3` as a parameter.

Comment: https://mortada.net/can-integer-operations-overflow-in-python.html. In Python itself integers can't overflow, but since pandas/numpy use C as the backend, overflow is real for these packages.

Comment: IT looks like it might oferflow between `x = lucas_n(1e4)[0:4442]` and  `x = lucas_n(1e4)[0:4443]`

Comment: Thank you - in combination, I'm happy to accept that there was an overflow in the underlying C backend. If you form it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have an integer overflow. In Python itself integers can have arbitraty precision, but since pandas/numpy by default use C data types, overflow can happen:

[enter link description here](https://mortada.net/can-integer-operations-overflow-in-python.html)

In order to solve the issue you might want to manually cast the data to Python integers:

```
def f(seq):
    '''Look up https://projecteuler.net/problem=739'''
    
    df = pd.Series(seq).astype('int') # Casting to Python integer type
    
    for i in range(len(seq)-1):
        df = df.iloc[1:].cumsum()
        
    return df.iloc[0]
```

This solves overflow issue in my testing.